# How can I use datefunction or put python date in below selenium coding.. Right now i am putting hardcoded value '2021-05-01' and 2021-05-31'

Tags: python, selenium, date, selenium-webdriver

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("txtStarttime")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('type')", element)

new_element = driver.find_element_by_id("txtStarttime")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','2021-05-01')", new_element)


#'value','2021-05-01'

element2 = driver.find_element_by_id("txtEndtime")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('type')", element2)

new_element2 = driver.find_element_by_id("txtEndtime")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','2021-05-31')", new_element2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
time.strftime(('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Out:

```
'2021-06-21'
```

Comment: It is not working in selenium python. If I put time.strftime(('%Y-%m-%d')) instead '2021-05-01'.. it does not work.  I want to put datetime function instead of actual date.. because I want program to run it with 1st day of last month and last day of last month...so if i run it in june it should pick may's date and in july it should pick june's date automatically

Answer (score 0):

Try [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html)

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

today = date.today()
d = today - relativedelta(months=1)

first_day = date(d.year, d.month, 1)
first_day = first_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

last_day = date(today.year, today.month, 1) - relativedelta(days=1)
last_day = last_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(first_day)
print(last_day)
```

Prints:

```
2021-05-01
2021-05-31
```

Then just `send_keys` with those values:

```
new_element = driver.find_element_by_id("txtStarttime")
new_element.send_keys(first_day)

new_element2 = driver.find_element_by_id("txtEndtime")
new_element2.send_keys(last_day)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help but still i am facing issues. When I put above code, it shows this error:- 'object of type 'datetime.date' has no len()'. So I used new_element2.send_keys( str(last_day)).. Now it is not showing error but still not able to see dates of last month in date box

Comment: I just updated the code, I think the string formatting was incorrect.  Give it a shot now.

Comment: Not working, is there anyway we can use last_day or first_day with setAttribute() function ?

Comment: I need to automate this site on urgent basis, if you want I can call you on google and show you whole code and website.

Comment: Sorry, not getting on a call.  I just tried my code on Google.com, and it entered the `first_day` fine into the search box.  Your issue must be related to something else, maybe you are trying to enter text where it can't be entered etc....  You'll need to figure that out.  The code above should get you started at least with the correct logic for previous month first and last day

Comment: It is okay, no need to be sorry I can understand. It is not working because in set attribute logic is to put attr name and value. so there it is not accepting the last day or first day as date. (setattribute( attributename, attributevalue)).... There is a calendar box where I need to put dates as function to automate it. It is not a text box.